# Is there any technique to do in postgresql 9.3 so that it start returning 1 and 0 instead of "t" and "f" for boolean type

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Actually i am migrating my ms sql server into postgresql 9.3 and we were using int data type to store 1 and 0 for boolean values but in postgresql9.3 it is not possible. what did i get when i did a little research on datatype of postgresql:

```
In Postgresql:-
For Integer type datatype:-

insert into ask(aint) values(1)         working
insert into ask(aint) values('1')       working

insert into ask(aint) values(true)      not working

select * from ask where aint=1;     working
select * from ask where aint='1';   working
select * from ask where aint=true;  working


*For smallint type datatype:-

insert into ask(asmall) values(1);      working
insert into ask(asmall) values('1');    working
insert into ask(asmall) values(true);   working

select * from ask where asmall = 1      working
select * from ask where asmall = '1'    working
select * from ask where asmall = true   not working
```

so if i want to use smallint then the problem that i am getting is , i can not compare any boolean field and if i use integer then i can not insert any boolean value eventhough i can compare booelan field. And

i can not use boolean data type as it return "t" for true and "f" for false
so what i want is?

1. is there any way to compare smallint with boolean?
2. Or Is there any way to insert boolean values in integer type data type.
3. Or can we do something so that boolean type start returning 1 for true and 0 for false.

So can somebody please help me? it's emergency! thanks

Comment: Hi..thanks for replying quickly, i edited now, actually my problem is, i want 1 for true and 0 for false after executing query instead of 't' and 'f'.

Comment: But still: why are you trying to do that? What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: actually i have written to show that we can use either 1 or '1' in different statement, any way i edited and written whole query.now you can see.

Comment: Again: what is the *real* problem  you are trying to solve? Why don't you just use a `boolean` and `true`/`false` when inserting/updating?

Comment: actually our project already supporting oracle and sql server and i want one more database support as postgresql, but all code has written to insert 1 for true and return the same and we are using hibernate3 also and it's work in both the databases, so now i want the same for postgresql. is it possible? have you read the all 3 question that i have written in my post?

Answer (score 4):

By default, there is no such conversion - implicit conversion is by default used only for data types from similar groups (e.g. `integer` and `bigint`).

Fortunately, you can always add new implicit cast if you really need to do so.

First, we will create a new function to convert `smallint` to `boolean`. To do this, we will use existing C function `bool_int4`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION int2(boolean)
  RETURNS smallint AS
'bool_int4'
  LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE STRICT
  COST 1;
```

Now we can create new implicit cast from boolean to smallint:

```
CREATE CAST (boolean AS smallint) WITH FUNCTION int2(boolean) as implicit;
```

And finally, we are ready to compare smallint and boolean directly:

```
select 1::smallint=true
```

PostgreSQL [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html) warns everyone that bad things can happen when you use implicit casting unwisely:

> It is wise to be conservative about marking casts as implicit. An
>   overabundance of implicit casting paths can cause PostgreSQL to choose
>   surprising interpretations of commands, or to be unable to resolve
>   commands at all because there are multiple possible interpretations. A
>   good rule of thumb is to make a cast implicitly invokable only for
>   information-preserving transformations between types in the same
>   general type category.

You can get list of casts for specified types from `pg_catalog`, from table [`pg_cast`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-cast.html):

```
select 
  castsource::regtype,
  casttarget::regtype,
  castcontext
from 
  pg_catalog.pg_cast
where
  castsource::regtype in ('boolean','smallint','integer') and
  casttarget::regtype in ('boolean','smallint','integer')
order by
  castsource::regtype,
  casttarget::regtype;
```

This will return (9.1.9):

```
castsource;casttarget;castcontext;
boolean;integer;e
smallint;integer;i
integer;boolean;e
integer;smallint;a
```

Comment: thanks Tomas, actually i tried the same cmd as you have written, and it's returning two more,"boolean";"smallint";"i"   "smallint";"boolean";"i" so is it safe to use them. and please tell me how to use them.

Comment: @Krishna What exactly do you mean? There are only four casts defined among `integer`, `bigint` and `boolean` in pg 9.3.1 by default, see this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2483). If you see more rows then you are either using different query or someone else already made changes to db configuration. If you run this query after creating casts than it is probably correct even though `smallint;boolean` was probably inserted by someone else. This modification should be generally safe, but don't expect any guarantee.

Comment: i want to cast boolean into smallint, sorry i am using ppas9.3 oracle compatible and it is returning 2 more as i have mentioned above, No nobody did any configuration, i just installed and did not do any changes. so can you please tell me the exact query that i can use to cast.

Comment: sorry i want to cast smallint to boolean

Answer (score 2):

if the column if of the boolean type then cast it to integer to compare to integer:

```
select the_boolean_column::int = 1;
```

to insert a boolean value as smallint cast it to integer fisrt

```
insert into t (integer_column) values (boolean_value::int::smallint)
```

to make the boolean_column always return integer create a view

```
create view v as
select boolean_column::int as integer_column
from t
```

When you query a boolean column it does not return `'t'` or `'f'`. It returns a boolean value, true or false or null. The string representation of the value is up to the client, hence the `'t'`.

Comment: thanks Clodoaldo, but i want internal casting. i don't want any change in my code. so is there any way to get 1 and 0, i am using ppas9.3